# What is the consequence of ignoring scala's advanced feature warning?

Tags: scala

I'm reading [this tutorial](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/functional-objects.html) about implicit conversion.

I entered this code in REPL with `-feature` switch:

```
object Rational {
    implicit def intToRational(x: Int): Rational = new Rational(x)
}
```

And I got this warning:

```
<console>:9: warning: implicit conversion method intToRational should be enabled
by making the implicit value scala.language.implicitConversions visible.
This can be achieved by adding the import clause 'import scala.language.implicitConversions'
or by setting the compiler option -language:implicitConversions.
See the Scala docs for value scala.language.implicitConversions for a discussion
why the feature should be explicitly enabled.
               implicit def intToRational(x: Int): Rational = new Rational(x)
```

But the implicit conversion works fine when I run this code:

```
scala> 12 * new Rational(1, 3)
res5: Rational = 4/1
```

So is there bad consequence if I don't follow the warning suggestion? (i.e. adding import clause or setting compiler option)

Comment: Only one consequence is too many warnings in compiler output, it's just annoying.

Comment: Import the feature and there won't be any warnings, you just have to be explicit.

Comment: Many unwanted kittens are born every late Springtime. If you can wait until then, maybe it won't seem so terrible that one of them is killed every time that warning is issued.

Comment: @som-snytt: so the implicit feature is a design mistake?

Comment: That doesn't follow. Some people don't like that SIP-18 is opt-in, so you must announce "I'm not an idiot, let me do this," but I have come to appreciate the safety feature. So the import is like seat belts in a car. California says "Click it or ticket."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Possibly in some future version the code won't compile without adding the import clause. Or if you want to use `-Xfatal-warnings`.
2. For other feature warnings (reflective calls in particular) you may actually want to eliminate them; this doesn't really apply to this specific warning. Read the docs, as the warning suggests.